# Simplify recursive equation $h(n) = \alpha h(n-1) + (1-\alpha)\delta(n)$

Tags: step-function, kronecker-delta

Can anyone tell me how to simplify this recursive equation?

$$h(n) = \alpha h(n-1) + (1-\alpha)\delta(n)$$

$\delta(n)$ is Dirac delta function.

I have got to this so far:

$$h(n) = (1-\alpha)\delta(n) + (1-\alpha)\alpha\delta(n-1) + (1-\alpha)\alpha^2\delta(n-2) + \dots\\
=(1-\alpha)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha^i \delta(n-i)$$

I guess this is a pretty common equation to simplify, and I know the solution has something to do with the step function, but I don't know how to get to that and can't find anything useful.

Comment: It is Dirac delta function. I've edited my question.

Comment: In fact I guess that you mean $$\delta(n)=\begin{cases}1,&n=0\\0,&n\neq 0\end{cases}.$$ (This is *not* the Dirac delta function!)

Comment: Then you can (indeed) simplify your result using the unit step function.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I thought we called this the Dirac delta function. So any guidance on how can I simplify it?

Comment: It is called a Kronecker Delta, not a Dirac Delta.